# I can't access a provided variable in rule action

Tags: rules

In a rule I have 2 actions, the first one provides a variable (my_var_name). But in the second action this var is not shown as available.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem with a different module with Rules.  I believe the data types are conflicting.  `node:author:name` is a string, while the value have calculated is an integer, a decimal or a float.

My Problem:

User Field - Voting Currency (set as integer)

**Event:**

- Vote was cast on entity

**Action:**

- Query database for the value of the vote cast
- *Calculate the value* to add/subtract from the Voting Currency field
- *Set the new value* of Voting Currency field.

I discovered the vote was a decimal data type.
I removed the Voting Currency integer field with a Voting Currency decimal field and everything worked!

Comment: Actually I attached an image to a Drupal issue queue of this http://drupal.org/node/1882086#comment-6911124

Comment: It was the same problem in my case. It was a conflict between an integer and a decimal number